# На моем сервере есть 2 IP адреса. Как отправить curl с указанного IP?

Tags: php, curl, ip, vds

На сервере есть основной IP и дополнительный.
Сейчас при отправке показывает основной ip 183.170.170.136
А я хочу чтобы запрос улетал с дополнительного ip 180.150.150.136

Это можно реализовать? Что где нужно прописать?

```
$request_params = [
    'posts' => '-159509706_6534564',
    'copy_history_depth' => '1',
    'extended' => '1',
    'access_token' => "token"
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getById');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request_params).'&v=5.131');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$wall_get = curl_exec($ch);
$wall_get = json_decode($wall_get,true);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($wall_get);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2425700